# Does compiler warnings cause intellisense to stop working?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, intellisense

I am using Visual Studio 2010 (c++), and Intellisense has stopped working. I've read that an error in the code can cause this, but my code compiles fine, I only have some warnings about a deprecated function, can this cause intellisense to stop working?

I tried deleting the .ncb file, but is not being regenerated. Also I read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235519.aspx) that I have to make sure that stdafx.h is on the include path but I dont have stdafx.h on my project and I have used intellisense without it in the past.

I don't know what else I can do to try to make it work, any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IntelliSense parser was completely rewritten for VS2010.  It no longer uses the .ncb file, it is now an .sdf file, a SQL Compact database.  If you program in the C++/CLI language then you'll get no IntelliSense at all, the current implementation doesn't support that language.  I've also seen feedback that C isn't well supported either yet.

Comment: It didn't work very well in VS2008 anyhow, so not much loss there.